# R - How do I create line chart to compare country data?

Tags: r

I have extracted data, and created a table for a health indicator for selected countries from which I need to create a line graph to graphically show differences between the countries.

[image: data stored in csv file]

I would like to have a line chart as follows:
[image: chart comparing selected country tuberculosis infections]

Comment: Check out `ggplot2`.  Here's an introductory tutorial to get you started: http://www.r-bloggers.com/basic-introduction-to-ggplot2/

Answer (score 0):

After checking out the suggested tutorial (thanks) and some additional research online, this is my solution:

```
ggplot(tuberculosis, aes(year)) +
  ggtitle("Tuberculosis") +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Rate", colour = "Country") +
  geom_line(aes(y = DRC, colour="DRC")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Algeria, colour="Algeria")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Kenya, colour="Kenya")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Mali, colour="Mali")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Namibia, colour="Namibia")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = South.Africa, colour="South Africa")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Sudan, colour="Sudan"))
# save to file 
ggsave(file="wdi-tuberculosis.png")
```

[image: Resulting plot from R using ggplot2]